# Unknow requests to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have developed an application in MVC.Net and MySql using entityframework. After hosting my application when i checked my error log it is showing below exceptions

1. The controller for path '/mysql/admin/' was not found or does not implement IController.
2. The controller for path '/mysql/dbadmin/' was not found or does not implement IController.

I didnt use such routes in my application but it is showing in my error log.
When will such request comes to the application.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably automated tools checking for vulnerabilities and assuming that you have a mysql web admin installed.

Comment: Yep. That would be my guess too. Simply, you can't control what requests come in. Any client can request anything. If it's not something your server responds to, then they get a 404. That's how it's supposed to work. Long and short, don't worry about it.